# Debo realizar una consulta de la fecha cuando el cliente tienes más de un registro para el mismo mes

Tags: sql, oracle

¿Cómo puedo realizar una subconsulta de dos campos?

```
DT_LETT_ANTE = Fecha Anterior 
DT_LETT_ACT = Fecha Actual
```

======

Por ejemplo la consulta hoy muestra asi:

```
C00030402   11/05/2020  08/04/2020      
C00030402   28/05/2020  08/04/2020
```

---ASI TIENE QUE QUEDAR---

```
C00030402   11/05/2020  08/04/2020      
C00030402   28/05/2020  11/05/2020
```

La lógica seria  fecha anterior verificar si hay un registro antiguo en el mismo mes.

Esta es la query que tengo que modificar:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        NVL(TLO.POD, 'NULL') AS POD,
        NVL(TLO.ENELTEL, 'NULL') AS CLIENTE,
        NVL(CASE WHEN PMS.CODE_STATO_PM = 'O' THEN 'ACF' ELSE 'ASF' END, 'NULL') AS STATO_CLIENTE,
        NVL(MATRICOLA_MISURATORE, 'NULL') AS MATRICOLA,
        NVL(CODICE_MISURATORE, 'NULL') AS CODICE,
        NVL(TO_CHAR(RUTA), 'NULL') AS RUTA,
        NVL(TO_CHAR(TLO.DT_LETT_ACT,'dd/MM/yyyy'), 'NULL') as DT_LETT_ACT,  
        NVL(TLO.CLAVE_LECTURA, 'NULL') AS CLAVE_LECTURA,
        (SELECT NVL(DESCRIZIONE, 'NULL') FROM DEM.ANAG_CLAVE_LECTURA ACL WHERE LPAD(ACL.CLAVE_LECTURA,3,'0') = LPAD(TLO.CLAVE_LECTURA,3,'0') AND COD_SOCIETA = 'CC01' AND GRUPPO = TLI.GRUPPO_CLIENTI and rownum = 1) AS DESCRIPCION,
        NVL(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(CODICE_MISURATORE,1,3) = '002' THEN 'S' ELSE 'N' END, 'NULL') AS FACTURADO_EN_TERRENO,
        NVL(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(CODICE_MISURATORE,1,3) = '002' THEN 'IMEDIATO'
        WHEN SUBSTR(CODICE_MISURATORE,1,3) = '001' THEN 'TELEMEDIDO' ELSE 'OUTROS' END, 'NULL') TIPO_CLIENTE,
        NVL(TLI.GRUPPO_CLIENTI, 'NULL') AS GRUPPO_CLIENTI,
        NVL(TO_CHAR(TLI.SECTOR), 'NULL') AS SECTOR,
        NVL(TO_CHAR(TLO.DT_LETT_ANTE,'dd/MM/yyyy'), 'NULL') as DT_LETT_ANTE,
```

Comment: Para poder responder tu pregunta, sería conveniente que dieras detalles del modelo de datos: cómo son las tablas y dónde están los campos que quieres obtener. Qué significa esa fecha que quieres obtener y cual es la relación con el cliente anterior, etc.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] y a leer [mcve]. En tu pregunta, veo mucho código de más y en cambio falta de información sobre cómo está almacenada la información. Sería conveniente también que incluyas algunos datos de ejemplo con los que esperas producir exactamente la salida que ya has puesto. La consulta que muestras, no solo está incompleta, sino que no hay posibilidad que saque solamente dos campos... ¿en realidad es necesario tanto código para explicar tu problema o duda?

Comment: Una subconsulta con dos campos, es equivalente a utilizar el operador estandar Lateral. En Oracle se utiliza como Cross apply o Outer apply (Cross=Inner join, Outer=Left Join). Donde la subconsulta que pones del lado del operador, se iguala por los campos que necesites a los campos de la tabla externa. [Oracle Apply](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1). En esta subconsulta, puedes leer otra vez la misma tabla para saber si hay algo anterior o lo que quieras, ya  que puedes referenciar a la tabla externa, y devolver varias columnas